# Locating zombie mySQL connections

Tags: mysql, unix, zombie-process

I have a colleague who has been using PHP's `mysql_pconnect()` without my knowing it.  We have had a number of instances where connections were denied due to a large number of zombie connections (per our sys admin who is currently not available).

What is the best way from the command line to locate/identify the zombie processes.  I have looked at the time columns in `ps aux` and `top` but I am not sure I am getting a complete picture.

Thanks.

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com/ Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL console `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` and look for these with `Sleep` in `Command` column and high values in `Time`. Then [`KILL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html)